# Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined list.min.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have used two plugins list.min.js and list.fuzzysearch.js.
When I use it in simple list, it works fine. But when I use it in ng-repeat, it throws error like "Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined at ...(list.min.js:1)..

search.html

```
<div id="testList" class="padding" >
  <label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="fuzzy-search">
  </label>

  <div ng-repeat="content in contents">
    <ul class="list" >
      <li><p class="keyword">{{content.ChapterName}}</p></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

controller

```
.controller('SearchCtrl', ['$scope' ,'$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("js/content.json").success(function(data) {
    $scope.contents = data; 
    var demoList = new List('testList', {
      valueNames: ['keyword'],
      plugins: [ListFuzzySearch()]
      });
    });
})
```

Comment: Did you debug any of this? Did you check that what you get is an array?

Comment: I can not see what is in demoList since I am getting an error. But in normal  search, I get an object.                                                                                o {reset: Object, listClass: "list", searchClass: "search", sortClass: "sort", page: 10000…}